# Race and poverty data at the census block group level?

Tags: us-census, demographics

I need 4 pieces of data at the census block group level for the most recent year available:

- % non-white population
- Poverty rate
- % Vacant homes
- Per-capita income

From what I can tell, the American Community Survey (ACS) 5-year summary data for 'Tracts_Block_Groups_Only' is the best source for this data, and the following data fields are the ones I'd need:

```
B01001_001 SEX BY AGE% Total population%Total
B01001A_001 SEX BY AGE (WHITE ALONE)% People who are White alone%Total
B17001_001 POVERTY STATUS IN THE PAST 12 MONTHS BY SEX BY AGE% Population for whom poverty status is determined%Total
B19301_001 PER CAPITA INCOME IN THE PAST 12 MONTHS (IN 2019 INFLATION-ADJUSTED DOLLARS)% Total population%Per capita income in the past 12 months (in 2019 inflation-adjusted dollars)
B25002_001 OCCUPANCY STATUS% Housing units%Total
B25002_003 OCCUPANCY STATUS%Housing units%Total%Vacant
B17001_002 POVERTY STATUS IN THE PAST 12 MONTHS BY SEX BY AGE%Population for whom poverty status is determined%Total%Income in the past 12 months below poverty level
```

Of these fields, however, it appears that B01001A_001, B17001_001, B17001_002 are only available at the tract - not block group - level.

I've seen maps and tables in other publications with race and poverty data at the block group level, but can't find it in this dataset. Is there another dataset, or are there other data fields in this dataset, that I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2015-2019 ACS estimates are your best bet.

These tables you can get block group level (sumlevel 150):

For non-white population, use table **B03002**. Subtract B03002003 (white alone, non Hispanic) from the total pop B03002001.

For poverty rate, the easiest way to get it by block group is to use table **C17002**. Add C17002002 + C17002003 for the population with income below poverty, then divide it by the total pop for whom poverty is determined, C17002001.

You should have no trouble using **B25002** for vacancy

Per capita income is table **B19301**, variable B19301001